# qgis 2.12 - Remove all TextAnnotations via python

Tags: qgis

I have maps with a lot of textannotations. I would like to remove them all from the python console.

I tried:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

items = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().items()
for item in items:
    print type(item).__name__
    if (isinstance(item, QgsAnnotationItem)):
        print "Got annotation"
```

It gets the graphics objects, but never finds an annotation item. How would I know if item was an annotation? And how would I then remove it from the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it gets your TextAnnotations but you get them in the form of QGraphicsItem.

But you have a methode data on your items and for you are looking for item.data(0) == 'AnnotationItem'.

So:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

items = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().items()
for item in items:
    print type(item).__name__
    if item.data(0) == 'AnnotationItem':
        print "Got annotation"
```